# How can I repair error when trying to access my home folder after installing Compiz in Xubuntu

Tags: compiz, xubuntu, xfce

I found that Compiz is usable with Xfce and after installing it, adding it to start with session and restarting session, I couldn't access my home folder (I have access to folders that are within 'home/user'). I get this error message: `Error stating file 'Home/user/.gvfs'. Transport endpoint is not connected`.

I unistalled Compiz and still get the same error.

How could I repair this?

Comment: interesting - this possibly might work for you? http://r3dux.org/2011/08/how-to-workaround-gvfs-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected-errors/

Comment: thank you. IT WORKS. solution amounts to manually unmounting the ~/.gvfs using:
$ fusermount -u ~/.gvfs  - then unmounting all that's mounted - then logging out, and in.

Comment: excellent - have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a rather old [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/212789) with your error message.

> After logout and following login every attempt to access $HOME/.gvfs
>   (i.e. with ls or df) results in 'Transport endpoint is not connected'
>   error message. At the same time $HOME/.gvfs is present in /etc/mtab.
>   Also GVFS-mounts are accessible through FUSE when
>   /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-fuse-daemon is called with some other directory as
>   argument.

A workaround suggested was in post#6

manually unmount the ~/.gvfs using:

```
fusermount -u ~/.gvfs
```

Then close/unmount all opened remote locations in Thunar/Nautilus and log out and back in, again.

This should restore the .gvfs-functionality

[source](http://r3dux.org/2011/08/how-to-workaround-gvfs-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected-errors/)